# Python how to insert extracted title from name field and add it to its specific column and index?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to extract the title from `name` field in a dataframe and append into new column using python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'name'])
df = df.append({'id': 123, 'name': 'Mr. Rooney'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'id': 124, 'name': 'Miss. Aniston'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'id': 125, 'name': 'Sir. Alex'}, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

And then I have the following list containing title names:

```
titles = ['Miss.', 'Mr.', 'Master', 'Sir.', 'Mrs.']
```

I've added a new column to the data frame:

```
df['Title']=''
```

Now I will iterate all the rows and write the existing title of each name at its corresponding row:

```
for idx, row in (df.iterrows()):
  for t in titles:
    if(t in row['name']):
      df['Title']=t
```

[image]

Apparently I am not been able to iterate over each index. I am new to python for data science.

How to extract the title for each row and add to its corespondent index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['Title']=t` is changing the Title column for all the rows. What you want is to change the Title for specific rows, so you need to specify the index in your for loop as shown below in the fourth line:

```
for idx, row in (df.iterrows()):
  for t in titles:
    if(t in row['name']):
      df['Title'][idx]=t
```

Comment: So in python index comes at the end `df['Title'][idx]` not like other languages where we start by the index itself.

Answer (score 2):

One line solution for your problem is as below.

```
df['title'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x : x.split('.')[0].strip())
```

[image]

You can avoid a loop in pandas by using **apply()**.
It executes faster than a loop.

Comment: Apply will iterate ? Can explain why you used `split('.')`? What if there isn't `.` in the text

Comment: And what if the title was between last name and first name?

Comment: As per my understanding title never come in between last name and first name If that is the case then that data is not valid data. @alim1990

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem. As per the given data I did it. @alim1990

Comment: In kaggles titanic competition it is in the middle. So that's why I am asking.

Comment: If that is the case then the **regular expression** is the best option. @alim1990

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

your pattern:

```
titles = r"([Miss|Mr|Master|Sir|Mrs]+.)"
```

New column `title` would be:

```
df['title']=df['name'].str.extract(titles)
```